# Matrix inequality for self adjoint matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be a real valued self adjoint matrix such that $a\|q\|^2\le (Aq,q)\le b\|q\|^2$ for all  $q\in \mathbb{R}^d$ and some $a,b \ge 0$, does this imply $\|Aq\| \le C\|q\|$ for all $q$ for some $C>0$?

I am trying to estimate $(Ax,y)_2$ as $|(Ax,y)_2|\le C\|x\|_2\|y\|_2$ and think that the matrix $A$ satisfies the result mentioned above, but, don't recall how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $A$ is positive as $(Ax,x)\ge 0.$ Thus by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we get $$|(Ax,y)|^2\le (Ax,x)(Ay,y)\\ \le b^2\|x\|^2\|y\|^2$$ Substituting $y=Ax$ gives $$\|Ax\|^4\le b^2\|x\|^2\|Ax\|^2$$ Hence $$\|Ax\|\le b\|x\|$$